# AWS DMS ( Data migration service ) - Replication is stopped without error

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, asmx, aws-dms, dms

We have recently observed that the DMS Task stops reading the archive logs suddenly, with no error.

Source : Oracle Database. Logs are been read from ASM.

Target : S3 bucket.

```

17:33:36
2020-05-12T17:33:36 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

17:34:35
2020-05-12T17:34:35 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Start processing online Redo log sequence 368461 thread 2 (oradcdc_redo.c:703)

17:43:37
2020-05-12T17:43:37 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

17:50:39
2020-05-12T17:50:39 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Start processing online Redo log sequence 368462 thread 2 (oradcdc_redo.c:703)

17:51:59
2020-05-12T17:51:59 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Start processing online Redo log sequence 368463 thread 2 (oradcdc_redo.c:703)

17:52:05
2020-05-12T17:52:05 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Start processing online Redo log sequence 354246 thread 1 (oradcdc_redo.c:703)

17:53:38
2020-05-12T17:53:38 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

18:02:38
2020-05-12T18:02:38 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Start processing online Redo log sequence 368464 thread 2 (oradcdc_redo.c:703)

18:03:38
2020-05-12T18:03:38 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

18:06:04
2020-05-12T18:06:04 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Start processing online Redo log sequence 354247 thread 1 (oradcdc_redo.c:703)

18:11:04
2020-05-12T18:11:04 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Start processing online Redo log sequence 368465 thread 2 (oradcdc_redo.c:703)
2020-05-12T18:11:04 [SOURCE_CAPTURE  ]I:  Start processing online Redo log sequence 368465 thread 2  (oradcdc_redo.c:703)

18:13:38
2020-05-12T18:13:38 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)
2020-05-12T18:13:38 [SORTER          ]I:  Task is running  (sorter.c:600)

18:23:38
2020-05-12T18:23:38 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

18:33:38
2020-05-12T18:33:38 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

18:43:38
2020-05-12T18:43:38 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

18:53:38
2020-05-12T18:53:38 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

19:03:39
2020-05-12T19:03:39 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

19:13:39
2020-05-12T19:13:39 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

19:23:39
2020-05-12T19:23:39 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

19:33:39
2020-05-12T19:33:39 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

19:43:39
2020-05-12T19:43:39 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

19:53:39
2020-05-12T19:53:39 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

20:03:40
2020-05-12T20:03:40 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

20:13:40
2020-05-12T20:13:40 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)

20:23:40
2020-05-12T20:23:40 [SORTER ]I: Task is running (sorter.c:600)
```

We can see that the Task is running but not reading the next archive logs for some reason.

Any suggestions where I could start investigating or any similar issues or possible fix would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?